# jquery .data() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

When I store an object like `{a: 1, b: 2 }` in jQuery's data, does it copy the object or save a reference to it?

I have a huge object and I want different elements to store different references from different points to the same object, and I don't want it to get copied.

Like

```
var obj = { 
    a: {
        one: 1, two: 2
    },
    b: {
        apple: 'yummy', banana: 'ehh'
    }
    c: {
        d: {
            'jQuery': jQuery
        }
        e: ['You get the point']
    }
};

$('div').data('info', obj.b);
$('#JQ').data('jq_reference', obj.c.d.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [my jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/u4KBf/), it stores a reference.

If I do this:

```
$('div').data('info', obj.b);
obj.b.apple = 'bleuch';
alert($('div').data('info').apple);
```

It alerts "bleuch", showing that a reference to the original object is being stored.

Answer (score 2):

It will save a reference to it.

Javascript objects are never copied, unless you explicitly make a copy.

Comment: I think the point of his question was to ask whether jQuery makes such an explicit copy

Comment: jQuery never copies things unless you tell it to.

Comment: sure, but where's that documented?

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/data/

"The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)."